# Is there a way to generate SQL from cakephp buildQuery function?

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp

I'm trying to find out what SQL is generated by a database read that is done from a model in my webapp. I'm trying to speed up the database call, (it's taking about 2 seconds), and I was thinking I might be able to tune the query. However, I haven't been able to find the query that is run.

I don't think I have direct access to the table object from my model. I found the deceptively named "buildQuery" that doesn't actually return a query object. Is there a way to go from the query array to the actual SQL query?

Comment: If you have access to the admin rights to server that the database is on and access to the SQL command line, you can do `SET GLOBAL general_log = 1;` before you do the request, then `SET GLOBAL general_log = 0`; after. This logs all of the queries to whatever file is set to general_log (`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'general%';`).

Comment: if you enable debug tool bar, you can see generated sql query

Comment: but maybe while you have not indexes in your tables, you have slow queries, so double check fields from WHERE query parts

Comment: You can also enable [SQL query logging](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/database-basics.html#query-logging) in Cake.